# ALB - Application based stickiness for gRPC target group

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, grpc, load-balancing, aws-application-load-balancer

Is the Application-based cookie applicable for gRPC target group?

I have configured an ALB with one gRPC protocol target group containing 4 instance as targets. I wanted to enable Application-based cookie for the target group, so that the request from the same user are directed to a specific instance for a define period. But i do not see any stickiness happening after turning on the settings.

setting -
[target group stickiness setting.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kpdyH.png)

client side code (golang):

```
func (r *gRPC) ClientRPC(data string) (*types.Response, error) {
    cookie := metadata.Pairs("cookie", "user=U1234")
    ctx := metadata.NewOutgoingContext(context.Background(), cookie)
    return r.client.SomeRPC(ctx, &types.Request{Data: data}, grpc.Header(&header))
 }
```

Server side code (golang):

```
func (r *gRPC) SomeRPC(ctx context.Context, req *types.Request) (*types.Response, error) {
    md, _ := metadata.FromIncomingContext(ctx)
    fmt.Println("Got the Request from Client", md)
    header := metadata.Pairs("set-cookie", "user=U1234; Path=/")
    err := grpc.SendHeader(ctx, header)
       if err != nil {
           fmt.Println("ERROR", err)
       }
    
    return &types.Response{Message: "Send Response"}, nil
  }
```

The client side and server side code is working, im able to get the response but the ALB is not taking "user" for stickiness. The request goes to all 4 instance randomly

Any idea what could be the issue?